How to wait for media element source to actually update with Async/Await?
I am using vanilla JS, webaudioAPI and canvas elements to create an audio visualizer.
When I update the audio element src with javascript, I need the audio element duration property to update two variables for my spectrogram visualizers. I want to use the duration property right after changing the src with javascript, but it returns NAN within the function.
Here is the code:
async function chooseTrack(trackTxt) {
  audioElem.src = `tracks/${trackTxt}`;
  await audioElem.load()
}

async function updateAudioContext(trackTxt) {
  await audioCtx.suspend()
  .then(() =>  chooseTrack(trackTxt))
  .then(() => {
      console.log(audioElem)
      console.log(audioElem.duration)
      frameLength = 360 / ((audioElem.duration * 1000)/ 3.2) ; 
      freqHeight = 250 / bufferLength;

  })
}



I can make it work with setTimeOut, but I would like a more elegant solution to access this property of the new source file within the function calls. This works:
setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(audioElem)
      console.log(audioElem.duration)
      frameLength = 360 / ((audioElem.duration * 1000)/ 3.2) ; /
      freqHeight = 250 / bufferLength;
    }, 50)

I'd rather not use setTimeOut to wait for the updated duration property in the function. What am I doing wrong?

the HTMLMediaElement load() method does not return a Promise - you'll need to create a Promise that resolves when the loadeddata or loadedmetadata or canplay Event fires

maybe this code helps?

ok thanks i'll try that. I also thought that calling chooseTrack() within .then(), even without a promise, would finish before the next .then() but I guess it doesn't wait.

@JaromandaX, it could be achieved by using audioElem.addEventListener('load', onLoadFn)...

@user2804429 - yeah, wasn't sure if <audio> elements would fire load when manipulating the source through HTMLMediaElement ...edit: <audio> elements NEVER fire load, according to documentation, so, no, that wouldn't work

@JaromandaX thanks. That is a very elegant solution with the canplay event to resolve the promise. I'll try that.

@user2804429 thanks yeah I'll keep the load event in mind, but the canplay event seems to work well.

@JaromandaX  If you want to check out the code or demo you can go to my github: link Thanks for the quick help!
